# Setting headers when using jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I'm using [JQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and I'm not sure how to set headers.

I want to be able accomplish something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/url",
                data: post,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("foo", "bar"); 
                },
})
```

but the beforeSubmit event dosn't pass the jqXHR object for manipulation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the [options object](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) you send to the form plugin actually passes the options to the $.ajax method. Therefore you can use the native before send function.

Comment: Here's an example to set the header with the request using the jquery ajax form plugin `beforeSubmit` function: `options.headers = {'X-Csrf-Token': window.Cookies.get('_csrf')}`

Answer (score 6):

The following code works for me.

```
$('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
    headers: {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
});
```