# submit form and include authorization headers

Tags: http, http-headers

I have a server that use Basic authorization scheme, when user tries to access restricted content, the browser will pop-up a login/pass dialog which I saw will further transmit authorization type header to server.

I want to implement a classic (pure html) page with login/pass edit boxes and a send button but keep intact the auth scheme on server (is some embedded very limited server, without php, etc.), so the form must send that headers too.

Is it possible? Or did I missed something in my understanding so far?

Thanks very much in advance,

Comment: While not an answer, if you've not read the HTTP 1.1 specification and referenced documents/RFCs then it would be worth doing so. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: I've read a little. Perhaps should I explain more. I try to avoid the 401 response which server will initiate when accessing restricted content. Instead, I want to give that credentials from html form if possible, at login stage.

Comment: Hopefully someone will give you an answer. If not I'll come back to it when I have more time.

Comment: I'd appreciate very much sir, I'm completely lost.

Comment: use `XmlHttpRequest` -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form