# Node js export generated json as file

Tags: json, node.js, http, express

My node server is generating a json object/array. I need to send it to the user, but not to display on the browser, but as a file. How do I do it?

I dont think writing it to a file and then using `res.sendFile()` would be a right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add header `Content-Type` as something that browser won't use to display it directly, then content would be downloaded as attachment.

If you want to name the download file then you'll have to use header `Content-Disposition`.

JSON object can simply be converted to string and sent with above two headers.

Following is the working server code.

```
http = require('http');
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    /**************** This is the important part **************/
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-my-attachment',
        "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"my json file.json\""
    });

    var jsonObj = {"name":"Will McAvoy"};
    res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});

port = 3000;
host = '127.0.0.1';
server.listen(port, host);
console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

`application/json-my-attachment` is a made up `Content-Type` name, since browser does not recognize it, it will try to download it. Otherwise you can also add standard header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

**Edit**

Regarding your second question, how to send parameters in `POST` request when downloading file, it can be done easily using `HTML Form`.

As you're using `AngularJS`, I'm assuming that you don't want your page to refresh by submitting the form. This can be done using an `IFrame`. Just update the IFrame's `src` attribute with Javascript to file download path.

It solves the page refresh problem but we can not send `POST` request `with body` using just an IFrame.

Here we have to use a `combination of Form and IFrame`. HTML Form has an attribute `target` in which we can specify the name of an IFrame. Form can specify the form parameters, action and HTTP method to use. Since the target is an IFrame it won't refresh the current page.

**Note:** Limitation of this method is that you can not send HTTP headers with the form submission though there are some [hacks available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form).

Following is working code. I have used [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) as the node server.

**HTML**

```
<button id="downloadFile">download file</button>
<form id="downloadForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/download" target="downloadIframe" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="param1">
    <input type="text" name="param2">
</form>
<iframe id="downloadIframe" name="downloadIframe" style="display:none"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#downloadFile").click(function () {
        var form = $("#downloadForm");
        form.find("[name=param1]").val("hello");
        form.find("[name=param2]").val("world");
        form.submit();
    });         
});
```

**NPM Installation**

```
npm install express
npm install body-parser
```

**Node Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

app = express(),
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.all("/*", function (req, res) {
    if(req.method = "POST" && req.url === "/download") {
        /**************** This is the important part **************/
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json-my-attachment',
            "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"my json file.json\""
        });
        console.log("body : " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
        var jsonObj = {"name":"Will McAvoy"};
        res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    } else {

        var filePath = req.url;
        filePath = (filePath === "/") ? "index.html" : filePath;
        filePath = path.join(__dirname, "public", filePath);
        console.log(filePath);
        fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stat) {
            if(!err) {
                res.sendFile(filePath);
            } else {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.end("file not found");
            }
        });
    }
});

console.log("server started at : http://localhost:" + port);
app.listen(port);
```

** Server output on download button click**

> server started at : http://localhost:3000
> body : {"param1":"hello","param2":"world"}

Comment: Can you tell me what to do at angular controller side? because the response comes, I tried using get. But I need to send POST.

Comment: You need to send post request to download the file ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending a few parameters, data is processed based on those parameters and then the json file is sent.