# Angular controller - saving received file sent by node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

My Node server is sending a file in response to parameters submitted by the angular controller using angular service.

Here's how my node server is doing that:
[Node js export generated json as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322621/node-js-export-generated-json-as-file/35323037#35323037)

It works with get request sent by browser.
But how do i save (download) it when it is received by the angular controller?

Comment: When you say "save", what exactly do you mean? Do you want the user to download it, or do you want to save it locally in the browser, or in the current web session, or?

Comment: download. Need to download the json response, as a file.

Comment: You can use file api provided by html5 [File Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/2535335

Answer (score 1):

This code can work:

```
function saveFile(){
  var file = {
    name: 'Jhon Doe',
    age: 55
  };

  var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(file, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});

  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  var a = $('a')[0];
        a.href = url;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

}
```

HTML

```
  <a style="visibility: hidden;" href="#" download="myData.json">download</a>
  <button onclick='saveFile()'>Save</button>
```