# Is it possible to set custom headers using javascript for non ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, security

I am sure about it is not possible with AJAX but I am confused with non ajax call.

For example:

I want to set custom headers such as x-requested-by:somevalue for non-ajax call (i.e. content-type=multipart/form-data) from client side. Is it possible with JS code?

Comment: AFAIK Its not possible. See this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516955/1225070

Comment: You mean IT IS possible with ajax right?