# How to add a header in a post request to a 3rd party api in gsp

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have a `gsp` , i want to call the API of a 3rd party but i need to add headers on it but i haven't found the syntax suitable for it.

Following is the code:

```js
<div class="container">
    <h1>Redirecting to Payment Gateway...</h1>
    <form action="${data.url}" method="POST" id="paymentForm">
        <g:each var="field" in="${data.data}">
            <input type="hidden" name="${field.key}" value="${field.value}"/>
        </g:each>
        <form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to set headers on a POST via a form.  See discussion here [How to set a Header field on POST a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form) for more info as well as some other options for how to do what you need.